# Javascript moment - subtract month at year transition

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I use moment at my javascript application and my code looks like this (at bottom)
When vm.reportMonth is 1 (Januar) and vm.reportYear is e.g. 2017 and the function oneMonthBack is invoced that previousDate should be december 2016, but it is still january 2017.
What I am doing wrong?

```
function oneMonthBack() { 
    var currentDate = moment().set('month', vm.reportMonth).set('year', vm.reportYear);
    var previousDate = currentDate.subtract(1, 'months');
    var month = previousDate.get('month');
    var year = previousDate.year();
    vm.reportMonth = month;
    vm.reportYear = year;
```

Comment: Please note that month in JavaScript (both for `Date` and momentjs) are 0 indexed. See [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) for moment reference: _Months are zero indexed, so January is month 0_

Answer (score 2):

I think that the subtract function is acting directly on the currentDate value, no need to assign the return value to previousDate:

```
var currentDate = moment().set('month', vm.reportMonth).set('year', vm.reportYear);
currentDate.subtract(1, 'months');
var month = currentDate.get('month');
```